# fastest way to insert 20 milion rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, migration

I am trying to migrate from one oracle database to another.
My Select Query is very complex and it returns about 20 million records.
When i try to execute:

```
insert into xxx
select a, b, c, bla blaa
from yyy join zzz join ttt etc
```

it takes about 20 hours.

is there any different way to migrate?
Can you give me any advice?

Thanks in advice.

EDIT:
i create a new table like

create table XYZ as select a, b, c, bla blaa from yyy join zzz join ttt etc

it takes about 2 minute.

and now i am trying to insert from XYZ to my original table.

left 15 minutes and it is continue:)

i will inform you :)

Comment: export as dump (use *EXPDP*) and import the same in new database. Its the fastest way.

Comment: @Grcn, Just in case, are you sure those are two databases and not two schemas in the same database. If yes, then as suggested, use `EXPDP` to export the tables, and use `IMPDP` to import the tables in the target database schema.

Comment: Based on your local table creation being fast, for further diagnostic purposes you might now try inserting into a new, completely empty table without any constraints or indexes in your target database, to see how long that takes. If that is also fast, try inserting from the new target database table into your actual target table to see how that performs. If it is quick, then you have a bit of a mystery - if it is slow then the problem is not with running a single insert into a remote table at all, but possibly indexing, constraints, triggers, materialised views etc on the target table.

Comment: Is the target table in use by any other processes while you're inserting into it, and do they need to be modifying it at all or just reading?

Comment: I am very glad that my suggested solution is working for you and it would be very nice if you give status on my answer by comment on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using SQL queries to move massive amounts of data between databases is probably the *worst* way to do it.

If you *must* do it that way, at least turn of all constraints in the target tables beforehand, they'll suck up a fair bit of CPU during the process.

A better way: Oracle provide utilities for import/export and unload/load, such as can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm).

Comment: 20 million rows ... I wouldn't really think of that as a very large amount of data, but we don't really know unless we have the average row width also. I also think it's a bit premature to advise disabling constraints on the target table if you don't know whether there are any, or what the level of work will be to re-enable them after the insert (possibly with the additional complexity of constraint violations needing to be resolved). That could be a net increase in the amount of work required.

Comment: @David, the phrase "I am trying to **migrate** from one oracle database to another" seems to me indicative of moving data to a brand new (identical) database, where the constraints can be added later (none of the data would violate the constraints as it cam from a DB that had the constraints on it). That's the reasoning behind advising that, though my reservations on it still stand - Oracle provides much better ways.

Comment: If this were a straight migration to an identical database then I'd be more inclined to agree, but I wouldn't expect there to be a complex query involved in a simple migration -- more of a straight select. If it was a straight copy of a database then I'd think first of using RMAN, or transportable tablespaces (license permitting). The cause of slowness on inserts could be index maintenance, constraint checking, trigger execution, materialised view refresh ... all sorts of things. It would be handy to know if this is a one-off or regular job as well of course.

Answer (score 2):

Which part of the operation takes the most amount of time? Is it the work involved in running the original query (time to return all the rows, not just the first row), or time to transfer the data between databases (are they on the same machine, or different machines in the same data centre, or on the other side of the world), or inserting the data into the table (both writing the data itself and the UNDO/REDO?), or the maintenance of indexes and/or constraints (if any) on the target table?

In general a simple insert into ... select from ... query is going to be the fastest way of moving the data, unless the network connection between the two is slow. Very large sets of data can be problematic because of a lack of intrinsic parallelism in the SQL*Net transfer, but 20 million rows generally doesn't count.

As a taste of the sort of optimisation you can perform there though, SQL*Net features compression of data sent within a packet, so if network time was significant *and* it is possible to provoke a better compression by ordering the data in the SELECT stage *and* the ORDER does not significantly increase the SELECT query time, *then* you can improve your overall performance. You have to consider all of those factors, though.

The SELECT query may return the initial few data rows quickly, but it may not be well optimised for returning all of the rows quickly. By default, invoking the SELECT as part of an INSERT ought to help but it is only by running an explain plan that includes the INSERT clause that you have any chance of knowing the actual query optimisation plan.

It may be possible to increase the speed of the data insert using a direct path insert (the APPEND optimiser hint), but that requires an exclusive lock, and there are some other documented restrictions also.

Export/import methods require the same query to run on the source database, then disk writes and disk space to write the file(s), then disk reads and network time and disk writes to migrate them, then disk space to store them on the target machine, then disk reads to read the files, then pretty much the same data insert options on the target as you have with an insert statement, so unless you're going to use tablespace transportation I would consider whether this is really an improvement.

So long story short -- what is actually slowing up the process Are you seeing high load on the source  database, or on the target, or on the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this thing, first create a table with your query and after that insert rows from that newly created table, for eg.

```
create table XYZ as 
select a, b, c, bla blaa
from yyy join zzz join ttt etc

insert into xxx
select a, b, c, bla blaa
from XYZ
```

Comment: Can you explain why this might improve the overall performance of the process?

Comment: I have already done this way for about 4 millions of records and it was very fast.

Comment: Why was it faster than a simple insert?